# Change name of the output column

Tags: r

As a part of the Recommender systems course at Coursera, I am doing assignments in R (https://github.com/eponkratova/projects-recommender-system/blob/master/recommender_knit.Rmd) and so far I got a N result.

Is there a way to rename col (var renamed_mean_1) more elegantly during the step where I calculate the average by a column (var dataset_mean_1)?

```
install.packages('gsheet', repos="http://cran.rstudio.com/")
library('gsheet')
url <- 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XDBRCYFTxsw27AivxJ5pWxDHN0WA6GqSP46PVe2BCQ4/edit?usp=sharing'
dataset <- gsheet2tbl(url)
dataset_mean_1 <- data.frame(colMeans(dataset, na.rm = TRUE))
install.packages('plyr', repos="https://cran.r-project.org")
library('plyr')
renamed_mean_1 <- rename(dataset_mean_1,c('colMeans.dataset..na.rm...TRUE.'='Mean'))
ordered_mean_1 <- head(renamed_mean_1[order(-renamed_mean_1$Mean),,drop=FALSE],n=4)
```

I don't have much experience with R, and for this reason, my code is a bit bulky.

Could you please help me?

Comment: You can reset column names using colnames() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
dataset_mean_1 <- data.frame(colMeans(dataset, na.rm = TRUE))
colnames(dataset_mean_1) <- "renamed_mean_1"
```

Or just to one call:

```
dataset_mean_1 <- data.frame(renamed_mean_1 =colMeans(dataset, na.rm = TRUE))
```